# Do not include weekends in date time

Tags: c#, ms-access

I just want to know on how to compute DateTime without including weekends (currently making a library system). The library is not open during weekends that is why i need to calculate the date that will not include weekends. 
Ex.
 03/13/15 = friday and im borrowing it for 5 days. So, the return date should be in  03/20/15= friday( because i didnt include the weekends)
 Can you please tell me or give me some ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: ( The program suddenly freezes when i type a number)

```
int days = 0;
DateTime deyt = DateTime.Now;
rd.Text = deyt.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
DateTime dt = deyt.AddDays(int.Parse(textBox3.Text));


DateTime span = deyt;
while (span < dt.AddDays(1))
{
    if (span.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && span.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        days++;
        span = span.AddDays(1);
        bd.Text = days.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
    }
}
```

Comment: Some code of what you are currently trying will help.

Comment: What do you mean by "without including weekends"? What computation are you trying to perform? Where does Access come in? Your question is far too vague for us to help you at the moment. (I suspect that in reality you'll want to exclude public holidays and things as well...)

Comment: If, as @JonSkeet suggests, you will need to account for statutory (public) holidays in addition to weekend days then you will probably need to use a dates table. One simple example of such an approach is in my other answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27249036/2144390).

Comment: I have my code now. See in my post as EDIT. Thanks

Comment: Right, so what you're actually trying to do is "add a number of days, excluding weekends". That wasn't at all clear based on "Compute DateTime". I'd also *strongly* advise you to separate out the computation from the GUI updating and general text handling.

Comment: Can you please give me an idea? I dont quite actually get it. Im sorry....

Answer (score 5):

If you have a list of DateTimes you can filter out the weekend dates:

```
public static List<DateTime> GetDatesWithoutWeekends(List<DateTime> dates)
{
    return
        dates.Where(date => (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday))
                .ToList();
}
```

Comment: I have my code now. See it in my post as edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now // Set your Date

if (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)   
{
//TODO
}
```

Comment: It would be clearer to use the enum value names rather than converting to int. It's not at all *obvious* what value 6 represents, for example...

Comment: Hiya there, while this may well answer the question, please be aware that other users might not be as knowledgeable as you. Why don't you add a little explanation as to why this code works? Thanks!

Comment: I have my code now. See it in my post as EDIT. Thanks

Comment: move this line outside the if condition span = span.AddDays(1);

Answer (score 1):

There are far more efficient ways of doing this for large numbers of days, but if your code is only ever going to deal with small values, you can just use:

```
static DateTime AddDaysExcludingWeekends(DateTime start, int days)
{
    // Do you need this?
    if (days < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Not implemented yet...");
    }
    DateTime current = start;
    for (int i = 0; i < days; days++)
    {
        current = current.AddDays(1);
        if (current.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ||
            current.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            // Effectively force "go round again" behaviour.
            i--;
        }
    }
    return current;
}
```

Or an alternative approach:

```
static DateTime AddDaysExcludingWeekends(DateTime start, int days)
{
    // Do you need this?
    if (days < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Not implemented yet...");
    }
    DateTime current = start;
    for (int i = 0; i < days; days++)
    {
        // Loop at least once, and keep going until we're on
        // a weekday.
        do
        {
           current = current.AddDays(1);
        }
        while (current.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ||
               current.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday);
    }
    return current;
}
```

Note that if you pass in days=0, that will return the original date even if it is on a weekend. It's not clear whether or not you want that behaviour, or whether it should skip to the Monday.

Answer (score 0):

```
  This is your code... Try.. 

        int days = 0;
        DateTime deyt = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dt = deyt.AddDays(int.Parse(textBox3.Text));

        DateTime span = deyt;
        while (span <= dt)
        {
            if (span.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && span.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                days++;
                bd.Text = days.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(span.ToString("MM/dd/yy"));
            }
            span = span.AddDays(1);
        }
```